# How to examine the relationship between items on one questionnaire with scores on another?

Tags: correlation, survey

How would I go about examining which items on one questionnaire are most associated with the overall score of another questionnaire and each sub scale of this second questionnaire?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1. You have the same individuals doing both?  2. What sort of items/scales are these? 3. What sort of association are you looking for? (e.g. linear, monotonic, functional, general dependence of any kind ...)  4. What is the purpose of this analysis (what are doing this for?)